# Which patterns can I apply to avoid method overloading all of the methods in this class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Currently I am looking at refactoring a class and having been studying up on design patterns, I'm curious which if any are applicable to this scenario.  How the current class looks:

```
public WebDriver window(int index) {//stuff};
public WebDriver window(String nameOrId) {//stuff};
public WebDriver windowByTitle(String title) {//title specific stuff};

public WebDriver frame(int index) {//stuff};
public WebDriver frame(String nameOrId) {//stuff};
public WebDriver frameByTitle(String title) {//title specific stuff};

public WebDriver alert(int index) {//stuff};
public WebDriver alert(String nameOrId) {//stuff};
public WebDriver alertByTitle(String title) {//title specific stuff};
```

now lets say that every single one of these 9 methods, I want to add an optional secondary paramater, that is a `Duration` for example:

```
public WebDriver window(int index, Duration of) {//stuff}
```

but I need such functionality on every one of these methods and don't want to create 9 overloaded methods, reusing a lot of the core code.  Each one of these methods creates a new `Wait` which calls a standard constructor to create it, assuming a default `Duration`, but I want to offer the ability to provide their own Duration as well.

What pattern is best to take care of such a problem?  I plan to rewrite the class completely but I want to create a good solid design.

My Thoughts:

1. Strategy pattern (WindowSwitchStrategy, FrameSwitchingStrategy, AlertSwitchingStrategy)
2. Some sort of Builder that when we create just one method we can build up state to decide if the duration should be passed onto the new Wait(); constructor or not.

Pseudo of window(int index) {} :

```
    try {
        new Wait().until(windowIsReady());
    } catch(TimeoutException ex) {
        //ex stuff
    }
```

would like an optional duration here, and if so we do this instead, but giving great reusability when we don't need an explicit duration specified by the caller:

```
new Wait(duration).until(windowIsReady());
```

Wait looks like this:

```
public Wait() {}
public Wait(Duration duration) {}
```

Thanks

Comment: all the methods return `WebDriver`, they are being created or they already exist and were found.

Comment: Add duration as parameter to current methods and allow it to be null?

Comment: @joakimDanielson that would not be backwards compat, would break too much client code.  I need to keep the public facing interface of this class the same, I could instead using a Duration... varargs?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is already in the code and should be removed first. If you use an approach something like this:

```
public static class Select {
    final Type type;
    // Only one of these should be set.
    int index;
    String key;

    private Select(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    private Select setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
        return this;
    }

    private Select setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
        return this;
    }

    public static Select by(Type type, int index) {
        assert (type == Index);
        return new Select(type).setIndex(index);
    }

    public static Select by(Type type, String key) {
        assert (type != Index);
        return new Select(type).setKey(key);
    }

    enum Type {
        Index,
        NameOrId,
        Title;
    }
}

// Now only one of each.
public WebDriver window(Select select) {
}

public WebDriver frame(Select select) {
}

public WebDriver alert(Select select) {
}

private void test() {
    // Easy to use.
    window(Select.by(Index, 1));
    window(Select.by(NameOrId, "hello"));
}
```

You can now add very simply the new parameters as now you just have one method of each type and don't need to add more to add other parameters.

Comment: Isn't it redundant to pass the `Type` as a parameter (and have an assert). We can determine the `Type` from the other parameter type anyway (int index or String key)